# Is it possible to save html web page on client side in session or local storage?

Tags: html, web, local-storage, httpclient, session-storage

I have save a menu code of my website in separate html file , and i include in on my webpages. 
which take time to render cause it is ajax call.
so there any method to save html page in session or local storage. ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you including the file with `ajax` call instead of `<?php include 'menu.php';?>` or `<?php require 'menu.php';?>` ? It is more reliable and fast, also as mentioned above both local and session storages aren't well supported at this time and date.

Comment: I am using node.js as back end and including file with angularjs include i.e <div ng-include='sidemenu.html'></div>

Comment: this method takes time because its an ajax call . rest body of html loaded before the menu file. so i want to store this whole sidemenu.html file in client side.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understood what is wrong with `php` method.

Comment: i dnt know anything about php :(

Comment: It's not much for acknowledge to include a file in php, what you need to do is to make your files with `.php` extenssions so they can parse `php` and then in the beginning of the file you need `<?php include>` function and you can write down your `html` content below it will work just fine.

Comment: Note that your files must have `.php` extenssions both `index.php` and `menu.php` to make it work, and every other page you want to include the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is an fairly new idea in web development.  Not all browsers are currently on the same page and so you will end up finding that sometimes your methods will work perfectly in for someone and not at all for someone else.  None-the-less you can use the new feature in HTML5 (localStorage and sessionStorage) to accomplish your task.

You can find an example at `http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp`

First:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Then, if storage is possible you can implement your code in the above if-case:

```
// Store
localStorage.lastname = "Smith";
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.lastname;
```

OR with sessionStorage:

```
if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
```

So essentially, at a high level you need to do the following:

1. You will want to create a JavaScript routine that checks if the user's browser supports localStorage and if so check to see if you already stored the sidemenu in it.
2. If you did store the sidemenu then simply load it into that `<div>` element. If you did not store the sidemenu then set the "ng-include" attribute (or do a manual ajax call) instead.
3. If the user does support localStorage and you ended up doing an ajax call, then all you need is a mechanism to detect when the sidemenu.html is finished loading and then dump all of the content of that div into localStorage.

Comment: This question and answer might be a duplicate.

Comment: I am including html5 file (sidemenu.html) in my webpages. like this `<div ng-include='sidemenu.html'></div>` .this method takes time because its an ajax call .  rest body of html loaded before the menu file. so i want to store this whole sidemenu.html file in client side.